# Installing 32bit distro onto HD from a 64bit Live boot

Tags: system-installation, 32-bit

I am trying to revive and old point of sale system with a touch screen that previously ran on windows XP. It's no longer supported anymore and it generally runs like crap. I've formatted the hard drive and I need to install the 32bit version of ubuntu. Every machine I have is 64 bit and no matter if I burned the 32-bit version to a USB drive or a disk I just can't get any machine to load it up. The point of sale system did boot ubuntu but the transfer speeds from what is most likely USB ver.1 makes it almost impossible to even load it up.

I had removed the hard drive and put it into an enclosure so I can access it with USB.

Is there any way I could live boot up a 64bit version of ubuntu but write a 32bit installation onto that drive?

At that point, I plan to just put the HD back into the point of sale system and let it boot up that way.

Comment: If you can find a raw disk image of a 32 bit install, you should be able to `dd` it on to the disk, noting that you'll probably need to fix the MBR / bootloader. Or, you could try running a 32-bit Ubuntu VM, attach the drive to the VM, and point it there for the install.

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites http://unix.stackexchange.com (Unix & Linux) OR http://superuser.com . Consider using the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck.

Comment: Hey sorry, i did a google for 'stack exchange ubuntu' to try to point me to the right place in the stack exchange network. I'm assuming you saw my post on the ubuntu forum? Is it against the rules? It's two completely seperate communities. I know the stack exchange has a faster turnaround for answers but I guess the ubuntu forum might help for something more specific like this where I couldn't find anyone else had asked this kind of question.